# Дублирование данных в открывшейся форме

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста неопытному студенту...
при нажатии на кнопку `Edit` появляется форма, в которую автоматически дублируются данные зарегистрированного пользователя. Потом эти данные можно удалить и ввести нового пользователя. Как реализовать, чтобы данные перелетали в открывшуюся форму?
[image: Открывшаяся форма]

```js
const editPopup = document.querySelector("div.root .edit-popup");
const userInfoButtonEdit = document.querySelector("div.root .user-info__button_edit");
const editPopupClose = document.querySelector("div.root .edit-popup__close")
//console.log(userInfoButtonEdit);


function actionEditPopup() {
  editPopup.classList.add("popup_is-opened");
}

function cardClosingEditPopup () {
  editPopup.classList.remove("popup_is-opened");
}

userInfoButtonEdit.addEventListener("click", actionEditPopup);
editPopupClose.addEventListener("click", cardClosingEditPopup);
```

```html
<div class="edit-popup">
        <div class="edit-popup__content">
          <img src="./images/close.svg" alt="" class="edit-popup__close" />
          <h3 class="edit-popup__title">Редактировать профиль</h3>
          <form class="edit-popup__form" name="new">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              class="edit-popup__input edit-popup__input_type_name"
              placeholder="Имя"
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="link"
              class="edit-popup__input edit-popup__input_type_link-url"
              placeholder="О себе"
            />
            <button type="submit" class="button edit-popup__button">Сохранить</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Перестать использовать такие слова как "перелетают" для описания поведения программы.

Comment: Спасибо! Приму к сведению.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос HTML, JavaScript и Ваши попытки это сделать.

Comment: В функции `actionEditPopup` возьмите значения из профиля и заполните инпуты. Вам поможет `document.querySelector`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!